# How to integrate $((x^2-1)(x+1))^{-2/3}$ using the substitution $u=(x-1)/(x+1)$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was asked to find the indefinite integral $$\int  \frac{1}{((x^2-1)(x+1))^{2/3}}  dx$$ 
using the substitution of $u=(x-1)/(x+1)$.

How do I make this substitution?

I attempted to solve this problem as follows: First I factored the denominator and distributed the exponent. Then I multiplied by one in the form of (x-1)/(x-1) to yield $$\int  {(x-1)^{-4/3}((x-1)/(x+1))^{2/3}(x+1)^{-2/3}}  dx$$ At this point I made the u substitution and replace all x with $((-u-1)/(u-1))$ I did some rearranging and got stuck with (1/2) $$\int  u^{2/3}(-2/(u-1))^{4/3}(-2u/(u-1))^{-4/3}  du$$

Comment: Could you clarify what your problem is?

Comment: is the $2/3$ exponent only for the $x+1$ term or the whole denominator?

Comment: the entire denominator is raised to the power of 2/3, I am sorry for the missing parenthesis, I am required to make the given substitution but cannot figure it out

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out for a week now, I was assigned this question and have exhausted all of my resources. I have a math tutoring center at my school but they cannot figure it out either, I have asked my classmates without avail. I tried to multiply by (x-1)/(x-1) and played around with the exponents but was unsuccessful. Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite straightforward if you write the integrand as:  $$\frac{dx}{((x-1)(x+1)^2)^{2/3}} = \left( \frac{x+1}{x-1} \right)^{2/3} \cdot \frac{dx}{(x+1)^2}.$$  Then the given substitution gives $$du = \frac{2 \, dx}{(x+1)^2}$$ and the rest is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

$$
du = \frac{2}{(x+1)^2}dx
$$
Also realise that
$$
\left(x^2-1\right)(x+1) = (x-1)(x+1)(x+1) = (x -1)(x+1)^2
$$

$$
\int\frac{1}{\left( (x -1)(x+1)^2\right)^{2/3}}dx = \\
\int\frac{1}{(x+1)^{4/3}(x-1)^{2/3}}dx =\\
\int \frac{(x+1)^{2/3}}{(x+1)^{6/3}}\frac{1}{(x-1)^{2/3}}dx=\\
\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^{2/3}dx 
$$
Using the sub now 
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int \left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^{2/3}du
$$
Which you can solve.